# Let $(Y_{n})$ irreducible Markov Chain and $\pi$ invariant measure. Show that if $\pi(0)\neq 0$ then $Y_{n}\cdots Y_{1}Y_{0}$ eventually vanishes

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, convergence

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $(Y_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a irreducible Markov Chain with $Y_{n}:\Omega\rightarrow M$ where $M=\left\{0,1,2,3,4\right\}$  and transition matrix $\Pi$ of size $5\times 5$ and invariant measure $\pi=(\alpha_{0},\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},\alpha_{3},\alpha_{4})$ where $\alpha_{i}\neq 0$ for all $i=0,1,2,3,4$.

Show that the sequence of products $Y_{n}Y_{n-1}\cdots Y_{1}Y_{0}$ eventually vanishes.

**Remark:** Someone told me this is a consequence of the fact that $\pi(0)=\alpha_{0}\neq 0$.
But I do not see as clearly as $π(0)≠0$ implies that the sequence of products $Y_{0}Y_{1}\cdots Y_{n}$ eventually vanishes.

Comment: If the chain ever hits state zero ($M = 0$), the product you are interested in will equal zero, right?

Comment: @Adrian That is what I want to show, that the chain always reaches zero, that's the same as saying that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}(Y_{0}Y_{1}\cdots Y_{n}=0)=1$. I do not know how to show this.

Comment: The complement event is that $Y_n$ never reaches $0$. This doesn't really jive with the chain being irreducible